# Decoding JSON nested dictionary using Decodable and storing it using Core Data

Tags: json, swift, core-data, decodable

I have the following `JSON` structure:

```
{
  "base": "USD",
  "date": "2020-04-24",
  "rates": {
    "CAD": 1.4049074074,
    "EUR": 0.9259259259
  }
}
```

I'd like to parse it to a class and store it in `Core Data`:

```
class CurrencyRate: NSManagedObject, Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case base
        case date
        case rates
    }

    @NSManaged public var base: String
    @NSManaged public var date: Date
    @NSManaged public var rates: [String:Double]

    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        ...
    }
```

From what I read in order to store `rates` field in Core Data, I have to create another entity  like this and create a one-to-many relationship:

```
class SubCurrencyRate: NSManagedObject, Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case currency
        case rate
    }

    @NSManaged public var currency: String
    @NSManaged public var rate: Double

    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        ...
    }
```

And the field `rates` in the `CurrencyRate` class would be: `@NSManaged public var rates: [SubCurrencyRate]`

The problem is I don't know how to parse the nested json with dynamic keys into these classes. How can it be done?

And how in general I can decode this part of JSON:

```
"rates": {
  "CAD": 1.4049074074,
  "EUR": 0.9259259259
}
```

into **many** `SubCurrencyRate` objects?

Comment: When creating a new entity and adding a relationship you do not need a specific property for this (rates) because the relationship will act as a property for rates. From a modeling perspective though it might be better to break the data into currency pairs and a rate and then you would need only one entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary that `SubCurrencyRate` conforms to `Decodable` but you have to declare the reverse relationship (also in the data model!).

```
class SubCurrencyRate: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged public var currency: String
    @NSManaged public var rate: Double
    @NSManaged public var currencyRate: CurrencyRate
```

To be able to parse JSON directly in Core Data declare two extensions

```
extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    static let context = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "context")!
}

extension JSONDecoder {
    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.init()
        self.userInfo[.context] = context
    }
}
```

In `CurrencyRate` you have to declare the to-many relationship as `Set<SubCurrencyRate>`, in `init(from decoder` decode the rates dictionary and map it to `SubCurrencyRate` instances. If the relationships are defined correctly in the model then the property as well as the reverse relationship is populated automatically.

```
class CurrencyRate: NSManagedObject, Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case base, date, rates }

    @NSManaged public var base: String
    @NSManaged public var date: Date
    @NSManaged public var rates: Set<SubCurrencyRate>

    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        guard let context = decoder.userInfo[.context] as? NSManagedObjectContext else { fatalError("Error: No object context!") }
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CurrencyRate", in: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        base = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .base)
        date = try values.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
        let ratesData = try values.decode([String:Double].self, forKey: .rates)
        for (key, value) in ratesData {
            let subCurrencyRate = SubCurrencyRate(context: context)
            subCurrencyRate.currency = key
            subCurrencyRate.rate = value
            subCurrencyRate.currencyRate = self
        }
    }
}
```

To decode the JSON you have to use the `JSONDecoder(context:` API in the extension passing the managed object context and to decode `date` properly you have to add an appropriate `dateDecodingStrategy`.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [blog post](https://ffried.codes/2017/10/20/codable-coredata/) about this some time ago.
Long story short: I'd recommend using DTOs for decoding into CoreData models. Given the fact that CoreData models are always bound to a context - which you don't have when decoding from JSON - it's easier to have simple structs that represent your JSON and then create your CoreData models from these structs.